# Unknown cause for segfault in C function

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

Why does this line cause a segfault? From what I know about pointers, and also from debugger output, the assignment should work.

```
int delimChar(char **in ){ //in is a pointer to a pointer to the start of a
  char del = '|';          // string with atleast two | characters
  while (**in!=del){
    (*in)++;
  }
  (*in)++;
  char *temp = *in;
  while(9001){
    (*in)++;
    if (**in == del){
      break;
    }
  }
  **in = '\0'; //This line causes a segfault, even though **in shows as
  *in = temp;  // '|' in debug output
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like the dbz reference :)

Comment: How is the string allocated? It's probably in read-only memory.

Comment: @Kninnug, thanks. I was running it with a hard cast string, aka, char *foo = "hdfsdlf". I forgot strings like that are read only. Atleast, I think they are...

Comment: @Kninnug - post an answer and I'll upvote

Comment: Regarding your edit: don't edit the answer to your question into the body of the question itself.  If your question is answered, then select an answer below, or write your own answer and select that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced it by calling the function wrong:

```
int main()
{
    char *ptr = "one|two|three";
    // Wrong! *ptr cannot be modified!
    // delimChar(&ptr);
}
```

Here is the fixed version:

```
int main()
{
    char val[] = "one|two|three";
    char *ptr = val;
    // Right
    delimChar(&ptr);
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I did not even know there was any difference between the two methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the string contains at least two "del" characters (e.g. "test | test | test") and not only one (e.g. "test | test")?

If the string contains only one "del" character and there is no gap between the ".data" or ".bss" section of your program and another memory-maped read-only section (under Windows this is nearly always the case) the following scenario is possible:

Your program always searches the **second** occurence of a "del" character - even if the string ends before! (This is definitely the case.)

The program will find a "del" character after the end of the string because the string contains only one "del" character. This "del" character is located in a read-only section.

You try to write to this "del" character (although you are already outside the string).

Just for curiosity: Why "while(9001)" and not "while(1)"?

Comment: Yes, I am sure it had the two "del". I defined it in main. Also, why not 9001? The compiler does not care. :D

Answer (score -1):

Without allocating memory, you cannot write into it.

```
**in = '\0'; //This line causes a segfault, even though **in shows as '|' in debug**in = '\0'; //This line causes a segfault, even though **in shows as '|' in debug
```

Is memory allocated for the **in ? where will it write, at what memory location will it write?
When you assigned just a character, it means it was pointer to the base address of that string. But that string is no where in the memory. What you should use is the following.
For example.

```
char a[255][255]; 
strcpy(a[0],"HELLO WORLD");
```

now, you can pass a. As you have allocated the memory for it.

Comment: `char a[255][255]` makes absolutely no sense here.

Comment: what is the double dimensional array? Can't you access it as double pointer?

Comment: the pointer is allocated because it comes from an already existing string.

Comment: **in = '\0';  is a crash - segfault -> Is *in is pointing to a valid address? Off course not, that's why he sees segfault. If you are convinced, then please respect my answer.

Comment: `**in = '\0'` can cause a segmentation fault even if `*in` points to a valid address.

Comment: @shreyasjoshi OP's function is supposed to be called by something like `char *a = strdup("HI|HELLO|BYE"); delimChar(&a);`. This has nothing to do with valid addresses or 2-dim arrays. The problem was that he was calling it like `char *a = "HI|HELLO|BYE"; delimChar(&a);` which meant that the string literal resided in read-only memory.

Comment: @us2012 +1 for telling me about strdup.